# Ulam Spiral mod p or mod p-twin

Tags: prime-numbers

I’ve been looking for anyone who has done this and can’t seem to find it. Would love some help with the visualization.

Create an Ulam spiral, but instead of using integers, use only primes.

I did this by hand out to around 700 and noticed that there is a set of twin primes in almost every arm. Wanted to see if this continues or if twin prime distance wins out over arm distance. Might also possess other interesting features, especially if drawn in the curved Archimedean way.

Another alternative is to do this Ulam mod p but using only twin primes instead of primes, so mod p-twin.

I have no coding experience and would love to see this visualized. I thought I saw somewhere that the twin prime distance gets big after p=20000, but could be wrong. Probably should have it drawn out at least double that. Bigger=better.

Much appreciation for any and all help provided.